# Greyscale to color CMYK option

Tags: adobe-illustrator

why does my color box keep jumping to greyscale everytime I highlight text to change the color?  Please help.

Comment: Have you checked if you document settings were set to Cmyk? Also worth investigating would be the options menu of your color picker window to see if a mode is checked...

Answer (score 2):

If you are by chance referring to the **Color Panel** (I'm guessing).. it jumps to whatever the *current* color is.

If your text is currently greyscale... then it jumps to greyscale when you select the text.